# Wheatstone circuit not functioning

Tags: arduino, resistors, gauge

I have 3 dummy strain gauges suffering no strain (all 120 ohms, G.F=2.1) and the fourth (same characteristics) is meant to pick up torque at 45 degrees on a rod. It has been verified on an external system that a reading can be obtained from this- around 300 microstrains are read on an external system with 3 120 ohm resistors. The circuit I have is mounted on an arduino (breadboard) and amplified by [INA125P](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina125.pdf). Is there any reason that I would not be getting anything when i wire my previously described arrangement?
Here's a picture of the entire circuit, the makeshift wheatstone with resistors is to the top left of the breadboard.

Note that this wheatstone bridge is not giving any signal whatsoever regardless of gain (I've tried measuring with gain resistances varying from 10 to 1000 ohms in evenly spaced steps, nothing is read. This leads me to believe that the problem is in the wheatstone bridge and no other part of the circuit):
[image]

I further dissembled a full bridge and replaced one strain gauge with the one on the rod in the picture. This bridge worked on my circuit; but the strain gauge on the rod still shows no signal.

Comment: Indeed - I wired it in a way which worked for another arrangement, again a full bridge, but this time all the gauges were on the same steel bar. Of the four terminals on the bridge, two opposite ones go into 0V and 5V to power the circuit, and the other two opposites go onto relevant amplifier pins. I've been checking to see if the fault was with the wiring with a multimeter, and I still cannot determine. I either get a 0V signal or a full (4.29 V) signal that I read. The gauges are soldered into the bridge on a separate piece of steel where the dummy gauges are; and the fourth is on a rod.

Comment: Schematic or it didn't happen!

Comment: Alright, I've got a schematic that I imitated from another person's work: http://cerulean.dk/words/wp-content/handsketch.jpg , this worked several times for me with different sets (other than the load cell shown in the schematic). In what I am currently trying to do, we have instead three strain gauges not picking up any readings, and the fourth being strained. Basically the only thing I ever vary in this schematic is the wheatstone bridge and terminals, to see what results I get...

Comment: In that sketch, what does "Analog O" mean? An output? You need an input, there.

Comment: It is used to measure voltage across. The Analog 0 can be identified in the arduino code as A0 and used to measure minute voltage changes.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the dummy strain gauges don't see any strain? You say it works with three 120\$\Omega\$ resistors instead of the dummy strain gauges. If the dummies don't see any strain, why are you using them in the first place? In a Wheatstone bridge you would either have one variable element combined with fixed resistors, or 2 or 4 strain gauges which work opposite to each other, so that the measured signal is doubled.

That [horrible thing](http://cerulean.dk/words/wp-content/handsketch.jpg) that you call a schematic looks OK, and your gain of 6000 should probably be enough to get some signal. Note that at a gain of 6000 less than a mV difference in the InAmp's input is enough to send your output all the way to ground or \$V_{DD}\$. You might need less gain.

I would try again with the 120\$\Omega\$ resistors.

Comment: I'm trying again with the resistors. Basically the three resistors are on the breadboard and the strain gauge is connected as the missing link. The terminals are wired to the rest of the circuit as shown on the horrible thing, but I'm still getting a flat line of 0.0683 volts....

Comment: I added a picture of the circuit as well.

Comment: I set the R_g as 100 ohms, that amplified my previous circuit (of identical strain gauge resistances) sufficiently. I realise that there should definitely be a signal, so I'm starting to doubt my circuit. But I'm sure that the problem is with the way I set up the wheatstone bridge, not the rest of the circuit...

Comment: To clarify, the wheatstone for which I DID make this work, was not with three resistors - it had 4 strain gauges on a steel bar and all of them were affected when the bar was bent. In this case I am doing it either with three dummy gauges (simply because they were readily available) or with three resistors. Neither methods seem to be working, so I do believe it's the wheatstone bridge that's the problem.